# Passing parameter into function to create variable name

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I want to use global variables in my workbook and in the ThisWorkbook code. I declared the following varaibles

```
Public position_1 as string
Public position_2 as string
```

If I want to see the value of those variables I believe they need to be fully qualified so

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.position_1
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.position_2
```

I have written a UDF which I will pass in an integer to represent which variable I am looking for.  I will only be passing in a single number and not a full variable name.  I am trying to find a way to use this integer to concatenate with "position_" to display the value of the global variable, ThisWorkbook.position_1, ThisWorkbook.position_2, etc.

```
Function Test_Global_Var(position as Integer)
    Dim variable_name As String
    variable_name = "position_" & position
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.variable_name
End Function
```

So when I call

```
Test_Global_Var(1)
```

my immediate window should display the value of

```
ThisWorkbook.position_1
```

Comment: Where does position come from / how will the function be executed?

Comment: Why not just save the data to a sheet someplace?

Comment: Not like that, no. For an example like this, you may want to consider using an array variable.

Comment: i wanted to make it simple by removing other info but what I want to do is eventually split() a global string variable into an array and return whatever position has been requested. i.e. Test_Global_Var(2) will return position 2 from an array called variable_name_array.

Comment: This can work with a simple IF - E.g. `If position = 1 Then position_1 = position`

Comment: Use an array for global variables `Public position() as String` and assign it with `position = Array(..)` in the initialization code.

Comment: `VBA` Does not let you do: `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.variable_name` if `variable_name` is a string variable. You can try `Debug.Print Eval("ThisWorkbook." & variable_name)` though.

Comment: @ja72 That's exactly what I'm trying to do, how to I get from a string to an variable.  I just tried the Eval() and it gave me a "Compile Error: Sub or Function Not Defined"

Comment: Since VBA does not have full reflection other than `CallByName` and `TypeName` functions, you only option is to use some kind of collection object, such as an `Array` or a `Collection` or a `Dictionary` to associate an index to a value.

Comment: So is it possible to do what I want with either an `array`, `collection` or `dictionary`?  I'm unsure of how to solve it with any of them

Comment: You are missing the return type for your function. Is it `Function Test_Global_Var(position as Integer) As String` ?

Comment: It's nothing at the moment as I'm just trying to get it to print to the immediate window. do I needed it I'm just doing a Debug.Print? When I get it working then I'll build up the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below produces the following debug output

```
2 values defined.
ThisWorkbook.Position(0)
First Value
ThisWorkbook.Position(1)
Second Value
```

It uses a private array in the workbook named `m_position`. The contents are accessed by a global property `ThisWorkbook.Position(index)`.

In a **module** have the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()    
    If ThisWorkbook.NoValues Then
        ThisWorkbook.FillValues "First Value", "Second Value"
    End If

    Debug.Print CStr(ThisWorkbook.Count) & " values defined."

    Test_Global_Var 0
    Test_Global_Var 1
End Sub

Public Sub Test_Global_Var(ByVal index As Long)
    ' Part of a UDF
    Debug.Print "ThisWorkbook.Position(" & CStr(index) & ")"
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Position(index)

End Sub
```

In **ThisWorkbook** have the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_position() As Variant

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call DefaultValues
End Sub


Public Property Get Position(ByVal index As Long) As Variant
    Position = m_position(index)
End Property

Public Sub DefaultValues()
    m_position = Array("First", "Second")
End Sub

Public Sub FillValues(ParamArray args() As Variant)
    m_position = args
End Sub

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = UBound(m_position) - LBound(m_position) + 1
End Property

Public Property Get NoValues() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ArrUndefined:
    Dim n As Long
    n = UBound(m_position)
    NoValues = False
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ArrUndefined:
    NoValues = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Property
```

PS. In VBA never use `Integer`, but instead use `Long`. `Integer` is a 16bit type, while `Long` is the standard 32bit type that *all* other programming languages consider as an `integer`.

Comment: Thanks for this I’ll have a look at it tomorrow and hopefully it will fulfil my problem then help me build my solution 

Comment: I guess  you can put emoji in comments now .

Comment: This works like a treat, one option I want to look at is, if possible. Let says the initial variant is called 1_postion and I create 30 of them, 2_position, 3_position, etc.  Is it possible to not only pass in a array position via 1_position(1) for example but also a parameter to ask for different variables without having to repeat the code 30 times.  What I mean is pass in 2 paramaters which will be 1: the variable number and 2: the position in that variable?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create the variable name from a parameter aswell as value in the array position passed in as a parameter too. e.g. (i)_position(j) where i is the variable array and j is the position in that array

Comment: So you want a 2D array now? It would be accessed with `.Position(i,j)`. The details aren't clear, so I suggest you post a new question as a follow up to this question.

Comment: Ok will do, but not a 2d array more so a way to pass in a parameter to change the named of the variable being accessed.

Comment: How is that different? Instead of using multiple variables, use one array variable. Unless they are all different sizes, then it becomes messy. Then you need a `Collection` of arrays or something similar. Remember, any time you feel you need to repeat code, stop and think about how to commonize the code using variable arrays.

Comment: Ah ok, I know what you're saying now, so using a 2d array I could have the first element as my different variable and the 2nd dimension as my value per say.  Could you get your code to work like that above with a 2d array?

Comment: A 2D array will require a `ReDim` statement to allocate space before use, and you can no longer use the `Array()` statement for storing values. The answer would be substantially different just because the piping of information flow would be different.

Comment: Thanks I've created a new question to find the solution.  Cheers for the help so far @ja72.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58764370/how-to-convert-into-handling-a-2d-3d-array

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to consider a global dictionary variable and pass data through it from the UDF. 
First add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime:

[image]

Thus, build the dictionary like this:

```
Public myDictionary As Dictionary
```

To initialize the `myDictionary` variable, consider adding it to a `Workbook_Open` event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set myDictionary = New Dictionary
End Sub
```

Then the UDF would look like this:

```
Public Function FillDicitonary(myVal As Long) As String

    If myDictionary.Exists(myVal) Then
        myDictionary(myVal) = "position " & myVal
    Else
        myDictionary.Add myVal, "position " & myVal
    End If
    FillDicitonary = "Filled with " & myVal

End Function
```

And it would overwrite every key in the dictionary, if it exists. At the end, the values could be printed:

```
Public Sub PrintDictionary()

    Dim myKey As Variant
    For Each myKey In myDictionary
        Debug.Print myDictionary(myKey)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for either.  I've updated my questions to try and explain it in more detail.  If your solution or my updated problem does work maybe you could explain to me in more detail?